# Reading and writing data via named pipe with demonization

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, daemon

I have two scripts: 
The first one ('Reader') is reading data from named pipe and the second ('Writer') is writing data to named pipe. I am run 'Writer' from daemon (daemon was created with double fork mechanism). If 'Writer' crash I want to print a message about it in 'Reader'. Please see following Python code('Reader'):

```
pipe = open(pipe_path, 'r')
while True:
    data = pipe.readline()
    if not data:
        print('Alarm')
        break
```

But when 'Writer' is crashing then 'Reader' is stuck on following line:

```
data = pipe.readline()
```

But if I run 'Writer' from terminal everything works fine (Alarm message is printing when not data in pipe). And everything works fine if I open pipe with:

```
os.open(pipe_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

But this method not suitable for me because I need to wait a time on start when 'Writer' start write data into pipe

In order not to create a zombie I do next in daemon:

```
def childHandler(signum, frame):
    os.wait3(os.WNOHANG)
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, zombieKiller)
```

How to prevent the 'Reader' stuck and correctly handle the signal from the child process ?

Comment: When the writer crashes does it actually die? Is there a thread or child process holding the pipe open?

Comment: make sure your daemon does not keep the pipe opened (and child processes should use `close_fds=True` to avoid inheriting unrelated fds).

Comment: unrelated: due to signal coalescing your daemon may create zombies. You could use `subprocess` module to start child processes (it has `cleanup()` method). Or use `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)` that is less portable but simpler.

Comment: Thanks to All. Named pipe was kept by daemon. Issue was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this in the daemon:

```
fdPipe = os.open(pipe_path, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

Comment: Thanks! As I told in my comment. Named pipe was kept by daemon. I'll approve your answer in any case.